# Using Facebook Dialog in Windows 8 HTML5/JavaScript App

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am following the dialog documentation to try to display dialog in a Windows 8 Store app (html5/javascript).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

In a Windows 8 Store app, we have to use iframe to display another web page.  Here is an example of what I did:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=145634995501895&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com&show_error=true&display=iframe&access_token={access_token}"></iframe>
```

Since it is an iframe, I specify display=iframe and access_token={access_token}.
If you want to try it, please remember to change access_token.

I get the following errors:

```
API Error Code: 110
API Error Description: Invalid user id
Error Message: Missing user cookie (to validate session user)
```

[image]

I guess this may be caused by the fact that user has not login yet.  In the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/), it said "If the user is not already logged in, Facebook will prompt them to login before showing the the Dialog you invoked."  I am wondering how to prompt the user to login?  Did I miss a parameter to prompt user to login?  I looked through the parameters, I did not seem to find anything.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing different behavior from you which I'll document here, even though it may not be "your answer".

I obtained my own access token, and when I use your IFRAME, I do see the attempt to redirect to Facebook.com to login; however, that's followed by a security error in the JavaScript console - including the following:

> APPHOST9613: The app couldn’t navigate to
>   https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=177388709024886&skip_api_login=1...
>   because of this error: FORBIDFRAMING.

A request to the login.php script generates a response with the [X-FRAME-OPTIONS header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) to DENY.  This would indeed prevent the login page from Facebook from appearing in the IFRAME within the app - hence FORBIDFRAMING.

There is [some discussion on an MSDN Forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/a1cba639-3251-4df8-abd3-b6f6a95ba4ae) as well and it's slightly dated, but am not aware of any changes since then.

I have not tried Facebook logins directly with Window 8 applications using [Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/), but it may be something to try.  Azure Mobile Services is VERY simple to set up, so you'll know very quickly whether or not there is still an issue within a HTML5/JS Windows Store app.

Comment: Jim, thanks for trying it out.  Your result is very helpful.  Since the login screen has X-Frame-Options header, is there any way to get around this to allow Windows 8 JavaScript app to display it.  I have read a few discussions on social.msdn forum, but has not see any help yet.

Comment: @JimONeil, Sorry, but I guess I am not understanding Windows Azure Mobile Services.  Facebook Dialog is client-only and is designed that way (to require the end user interaction) to avoid spam.  So I am not sure how a server-side service will help?  Note: please feel free to correct me, I would love to be wrong on this one.

Several important Facebook apis are only available through dialogs, and is not available through Graph api.

Comment: another option is [WebAuthenticationBroker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465281.aspx)